# Best practices to define response in action controller Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a method inside `PostController`

```
class PostController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return response($posts);   
    }
}
```

Two way:

```
class PostController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return $posts;   
    }
}
```

Both work fine but which way is better and more correctly?

Comment: It doesn't matter at all. So long as you keep it consistent throughout your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personnaly prefer this version:

```
return \Response::json($data);
```

Because it makes clear that the response is actual json data.

Just make sure your code is understandable by someone new on your project.

If you are writing an API project, where everything is always returned in json, simply return the model because you don't have to make the reader learn that it's JSON because everything is in JSON everywhere.

On the other hand, if it's some sort of mixed project (some routes return view, JSON, XML, whatever), try to make is as obvious as you can that this specific route return JSON data and nothing else.

Also as stated in comments, stay consistent. The shorter isn't the better. The better is the one that is simple to read and give enough info about what's going on.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but I prefer `return response()->json($data);`. That way you don't need to import another class and still have their benefits

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter actually.. its depends on your desire and consistency..

```
return Response::json($model);
//or
return response()->json($model);
//or
return $model;
```

it give you same output..but if you using `response`, you can set the status code. most of the time, this reponse thing is used in API project.